# Rails Strong parameters ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, strong-parameters

Hi I know that Rails 4 is using strong parameters and i need to allow them in controller which is what i do but i still get this error.

My request looks like

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"cAJLJGiywr4TeAEpidQ1/XstiSNO+819W4QBhgMGNczVret+H/XDDVk3l1UpoaK8tHVK6qf+KK8VjBdM51zocA==",
"estate"=>{"building_id"=>"1",
"planet_id"=>"1",
"number"=>"2"},
"commit"=>"Build",
"locale"=>"en"}
```

In my controller i tried

```
def estate_params
    params.require(:estate).permit(:building_id, :planet_id, :number)
end


@estate = Estate.new(estate_params)
```

or

```
Estate.new(params[:estate].permit(:building_id, :planet_id, :number))
```

can anyone explain to me why do i get this error ?

Thanks

Full Trace

```
.bundle/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in     `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:557:in `init_attributes'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:280:in `initialize'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
.bundle/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:85:in `build_resource'
.bundle/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:66:in `load_resource_instance'
.bundle/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
.bundle/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
.bundle/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `instance_exec'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `block in make_lambda'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `block in halting'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
```

.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in`call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in`block in process_action'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`process_action'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
.bundle/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in`process'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in`dispatch'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in`serve'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`each'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in`call'
.bundle/gems/rack-pjax-0.8.0/lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
.bundle/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
.bundle/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
.bundle/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in`call'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
.bundle/gems/remotipart-1.2.1/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in`call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in`call'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
.bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in`call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in`_run_call_callbacks'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in`call'
.bundle/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:59:in `call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
.bundle/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:31:in `call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
.bundle/gems/quiet_assets-1.1.0/lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
.bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in`call'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call'
.bundle/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
.bundle/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in`catch'
.bundle/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
.bundle/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in`process'
.bundle/gems/faye-websocket-0.10.0/lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:40:in `process'
.bundle/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in`receive_data'
.bundle/gems/faye-websocket-0.10.0/lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:44:in `receive_data'
.bundle/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in`run_machine'
.bundle/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
.bundle/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in`start'
.bundle/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in`run'
.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in`start'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:8:in`require'
bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
.bundle/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`load'
.bundle/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
.bundle/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`call'
.bundle/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
.bundle/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in`'
.bundle/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
.bundle/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`'
bin/spring:13:in `require'
bin/spring:13:in`'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in`'

Comment: This seems okay. Can you post the full error message with stack trace?

Comment: Are you migrating from Rails 3?

Comment: No Im not migrating, Just to be sure, im having the form on Planet view but that should be all ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to the top of the controller (Assuming this is a POST to create a new `Estate`)

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:create]
```

Comment: This worked but why do i need to do that ?

ability is :

    "can [:create], Estate"

Comment: The reason is that you are asking ``cancan`` to load and authorize a resource, which is happening prior to even calling the ``create`` method in the controller. So your code in ``estate_params`` does not get called. This is a typical error occurring when migrating from Rails 3 to Rails 4

Comment: This is weird because im not migrating, does that mean that i need use load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:create] in each of my controllers ? a little strange isnt it ?

Comment: Yes, you should be using it in every controller. The logic is this: Why do you need to load and authorize a resource that does not exist yet?

Comment: Youre right in my other controllers im using load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]